# R how to make a new variable which refers to specific values in another dataframe

Tags: r, indexing, time-series, subset, lookup

I am attempting to average a biological rate throughout varied observation periods.
The start and end times are in my data frame (df) and the measured rates in a second data frame (rates). The data was collected per hour, but I want to  mean average the rates for each observation period.

My data set is much bigger than this (~10k observations) and there are more variables, but I hope this reproducible example can help find a solution.

```
## start and end date-times for observation periods.  
df<- data.frame(observation = 1:4,
      start.time= c(as.POSIXct("2021-01-01 00:35"), as.POSIXct("2021-01-02 14:35"), as.POSIXct("2021-01-03 07:31"), as.POSIXct("2021-01-04 19:02")),
      end.time = c(as.POSIXct("2021-01-01 12:38"), as.POSIXct("2021-01-02 14:47"), as.POSIXct("2021-01-04 00:54"), as.POSIXct("2021-01-05 05:19")))

## rates observed                      
data = data.frame(time = seq(as.POSIXct("2021-01-01 00:00"), 
                     as.POSIXct("2021-01-05 23:59"), by = "hour"),
                     rate=rnorm(1:120))
```

Comment: Can you please set the seed for `data` and include the expected outcome or the desired method to calculate mean. Actually I thought that you need weighted means here because the time intervals are not of equal lengths

Comment: Since you haven't accepted any of the answer can you please clarify, what'd be an expected outcome say if obs1 starts at 01:59:00 and end at 02:59:00 thus lasting one hour exactly, but rates at 01:00:00 be say 1 and at 02:00:00 be say 2?  Would the expected average be just (1+2)/2 = 1.5 or (1*1 + 2*59)/60 = 1.98??  Please clarify

Answer (score 1):

We can use the family of `apply` functions. It simply is a variant of for loop. For example

**Using for loop**

```
mean_rate <- c()
for (i in c(1:nrow(df)){
  mean_rate[i] <- mean(data$rate[data$time >= df$start.time[i] & data$time < df$end.time[i]])
}
data$mean_rate <- mean_rate
```

**Using `sapply`**

```
df$mean_rate <- sapply(c(1:nrow(df), function(i){
  mean(data$rate[data$time >= df$start.time[i] & data$time < df$end.time[i]])
})
```

**Using `mapply`**

```
df$mean_rate <- mapply(function(x, y){
  mean(data$rate[data$time >= x & data$time < y])
}, df$start.time, df$end.time)
```

Comment: thanks so much for you suggestions. Do the loop / apply functions average all of the observaton between specified start and end times, or do they only calculate the average between the starting and ending values?

Answer (score 0):

A tidyverse option.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

data %>%
  crossing(interval(df$start.time, df$end.time), 
           .name_repair = ~ str_sub(., 1, 8)) %>%
  filter(time %within% interval) %>%
  group_by(interval) %>%
  summarise(meanRate = mean(rate))

# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   interval                                         meanRate
#   <Interval>                                          <dbl>
# 1 2021-01-01 00:35:00 CET--2021-01-01 12:38:00 CET  -0.0938
# 2 2021-01-03 07:31:00 CET--2021-01-04 00:54:00 CET   0.0360
# 3 2021-01-04 19:02:00 CET--2021-01-05 05:19:00 CET  -0.191
```

Comment: thank you for your response! I could not get the 'crossing' function to work so I did not use this solution.

Comment: @Rnewbie: You are very welcome. How come ```crossing()``` didn't work? What error message did you get?

Answer (score 0):

Would this a long approach work for you? It however, attempts to calculate mean for weighted part of the interval.

```r
df<- data.frame(observation = 1:4,
                start.time= c(as.POSIXct("2021-01-01 00:35"), as.POSIXct("2021-01-02 14:35"), as.POSIXct("2021-01-03 07:31"), as.POSIXct("2021-01-04 19:02")),
                end.time = c(as.POSIXct("2021-01-01 12:38"), as.POSIXct("2021-01-02 14:47"), as.POSIXct("2021-01-04 00:54"), as.POSIXct("2021-01-05 05:19")))

## rates observed                      
set.seed(1)
data = data.frame(time = seq(as.POSIXct("2021-01-01 00:00"), 
                             as.POSIXct("2021-01-05 23:59"), by = "hour"),
                  rate=rnorm(1:120))

suppressMessages(library(tidyverse))
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(dummy = hour(start.time) == hour(end.time)) %>%
  pivot_longer(!c(observation, dummy)) %>%
  group_by(observation) %>%
  mutate(val2 = floor_date(value, unit = 'hour'),
         interv = case_when(dummy & name == 'end.time' ~ difftime(value, value, units = 'secs'),
                            dummy ~ difftime(value[name == 'end.time'], value[name == 'start.time'], units = 'secs'),
                            name == 'start.time'~ 3600 - difftime(value, val2, units = 'secs'),
                          TRUE ~ difftime(value, val2, units = 'secs'))) %>%
  complete(val2 = seq.POSIXt(min(val2), max(val2), by = 'hours'), fill = list(interv = 60*60)) %>%
  left_join(data, by = c('val2' = 'time')) %>%
  summarise(mean_rate = sum(as.numeric(interv) * rate)/sum(as.numeric(interv)))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   observation mean_rate
#>         <int>     <dbl>
#> 1           1    0.265 
#> 2           2    1.10  
#> 3           3    0.277 
#> 4           4    0.0991
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>